# Excel return formula from Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need help making a function that returns the equation of a cell without the equal sign.   Can be done in google sheets, Excel, VBA, or Google App Scripts.

Example below

Instead of typing out A1+A2, can I type a formula into cell C1 that returns string A1+A2 from cell B2.

B2 Formula =A1+A2

C2 Value I would like A1+A2

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWiTt.png)

Comment: what have you tried so far? please re-read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your attempts. Depending on what version of Excel you're using, there's actually a built-in formula that does this (although it includes the "=" sign, that can easily be removed with other built-in functions.

Comment: If you are using Office365 there is `=FORMULATEXT(...)`  Before that, vba was required

Answer (score 1):

Try this quick user defined function.

```
function whatFormula(rng as range)
    set rng = rng.cells(1)
    if rng.hasformula then _
        whatFormula = mid(rng.formula, 2)
end function
```

Comment: I liked it - neat.